# Why does P = $\rho$gh seem to contradict equal accelerations of fluids in a closed U tube?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

This is based on a problem. The closed U tube is as shown : 
[image]

I want to figure out time period of small oscillations if the liquid interface is slightly disturbed.
My take :  considering an displacement '$x$' from the initial level,
[image]

The difference in pressure exerted by the liquid of density $\rho_2$ at the two interfaces = $2xSg\rho_2$
This should equal the net force exerted on liquid with density $\rho_1$.
Thus by equating $$F = ma$$

[image]

This gives angular frequency, $\omega$ as $\frac{2g\rho_2}{l\rho_1}$
 However, when I write the force equation for the other liquid, I get a different angular frequency. This seems to contradict the fact that both the liquids have equal accelerations.
What's wrong here?

Comment: You're using an equation for hydrostatic friction in a non-static situation.

Comment: If so, how can I account for the forces moving the liquids?

Comment: You can use $x$ as a generalized coordinate and write down the Lagrangian for your system in terms of $x$ and $\dot x$. You should find that the kinetic energy is proportional to $\dot x^2$, whereas the potential energy is proportional to $x^2$. From here, you should have no problem to derive the equation of motion, which will give you the oscillation frequency.

Comment: I think that the restoring force that you're trying to calculate should be proportional not to $\rho_2$ or $\rho_1$ but to the difference between the two densities (i.e., F=2xSg($\rho_1$-$\rho_2$) ). Note that the restoring force should equal zero when $\rho_1$=$\rho_2$. Also, I don't think that the expression you wrote for the mass $m$ is correct, either. It should also depend on $\rho_2$ as well as $\rho_1$.

Comment: @knzhou Sounds like an answer

Comment: @SamuelWeir  can you provide an answer please?